# Why don't checkboxes appear in some Android browsers for my site?

Tags: android

I've got some forms with checkboxes on my development website and the checkboxes don't show up consistently on the Android browsers on my phone.

To be more specific, the checkboxes show up fine in Chrome, Firefox and Edge on my laptop (running Windows 10) and also in Firefox in Android 8 but NOT in Brave or Samsung Internet, also in Android 8.

Initially, I thought perhaps checkboxes simply aren't supported in Brave or the Samsung Internet browsers on Android 8 but I've now disproven that. Apparently, I've done *something* that keeps the checkboxes from appearing in those two browsers but NOT in Firefox on the same Android 8 device. Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?

This link to my development environment should illustrate the issue:
[my development site](http://sfl-w3.epizy.com/topicProposalBook.php)

I should be seeing checkboxes in front of all of the following in ALL browsers:

1. "The proposer has attended at least three full meetings of Science Fiction London"
2. "The proposer has read the work recently"
3. "The book is available at the local library"
4. "The book is available for purchase...."
5. "X copies will be circulated...."
6. "The book can be read online...."
7. "Member can obtain the book...."
8. "There is a related topic...."
9. All six of the dates that appear in the unordered list just before the Submit and Reset buttons.

Comment: Can you provide some html source code of your checkboxes?  Stackoverflow encourages showing source, error messages and what you've tried.

Comment: @kristianp I've edited my post to add a link that illustrates the problem, which should be even better than a code snippet without proper context.

Comment: I'm revising my question. I found another page that contains checkboxes - https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_input.asp - and the checkboxes display just fine in Brave and Samsung Internet on Android 8. I had assumed the browsers were the problem and just didn't support checkboxes but instead, I must have shot myself in the foot with my own CSS. I'll investigate that now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this little mystery, although I'm baffled by the solution. In a nutshell, I found that renaming one of my CSS files, from body.css to main.css, resolved the problem! (Using foo.css also worked but I changed it again to make a more professional name.) Somehow, the *NAME* of the stylesheet file - not the contents - was the problem and simply changing the name fixed it so that now my checkboxes appear in ALL browsers.

Since this solution makes no sense to me,  I've created a separate question to see if anyone can suggest WHY changing the name of the stylesheet should solve the problem.